# JSTREE - Double click for links and single click for expanding tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm trying to create a jstree list where nodes open on single click, but open the node's respective link on double click.
I need the plugin "state" to work as well.

This is what I have right now:

HTML:

```
<div id="jstree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="1">ME2 Engineering</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="3">Maths</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="13">2nd Order Differential Equations</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>           
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="4">Mechatronics</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="14">Control</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="15">Electronics</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>           
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="12">Dynamics</a>
                </li>
            </ul>                                            
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#jstree').jstree({
        "core" : { 
            "check_callback" : true,
            "dblclick_toggle" :false
        },
        "types" : {
            "default" : {
                "icon" : "glyphicon glyphicon-grain"
            },
            "root" : {
                "icon" : "glyphicon glyphicon-tree-deciduous"
            }
        },
        "plugins" : ["dnd", "types", "state"]
    }).on('click', '.jstree-anchor', function (e) {
        $('#jstree').jstree(true).toggle_node(e.target);
    }).bind("dblclick.jstree", function (event) {
       var node = $(event.target).closest("li");
       var data = node.data("jstree");
       // Do my action
       var href = node.a_attr.href;
       document.location.href = href;
    }); 
});
```

I have managed to get the individual events of my problem to work when done separately - i.e. I can make a node link open on single click, but even with this I can't get "state" to work -> the page ends up never loading as it always points the initially clicked link.

Currently the code above lets me open nodes on single click but does nothing on double click. State works fine as well. I believe a fix can easily be found once I can get the href data from the selected node, any idea on how to do this?